# Object Particles Won't Render in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

Says it right in the title. I'm trying to render particles in cycles, I have everything visible and the particles are assigned as objects. I'm sure I'm doing everything right, but obviously I'm not. Any help?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9cqpgo47n7qe4x/Dyson%20Sphere.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Check *Camera* visibility in Object Tab -> Cycles settings

[image]